# How do I add Date of birth to DateTime c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to add the Date of birth variable

```
person.Add(new Person { personId = 1, name = "Zandile", surname = "Manatha", dateOfBirth = DateTime(05/30/2015),  department = "Human Resource"});
```

But DateTime is not working how do I add it correctly.

Comment: You need to properly create an instance of `DateTime` by calling it's constructor, such as `dateOfBirth = new DateTime(2015,5,30)`

Comment: Did you look at the [DateTime documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Use `DateTime.Parse("05/30/2015")` instead of `DateTime(05/30/2015) `.

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
dateOfBirth = new DateTime(2015, 5, 30)
```

instead of

```
dateOfBirth = DateTime(05/30/2015)
```

because `05/30/2015` performs as arithmetic division and it returns `0`.

Further reading:

- [`DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)